# While using beautifulsoup4 and selenium, output a None value if a an element is inexstant on the page

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Good time of the day,

Currently I work on scraping project with the end goal is to create a DataFrame.
While I navigate from page to page, I have to gather different criterias. Though In case if the criteria is not present on the page, I would like to receive a "None"

```
import re

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import random
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
start_time = time.time()

url='https://www.immoweb.be/en/search/house/for-sale?countries=BE&page=1&orderBy=relevance'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(random.uniform(1.0, 3.0))
python_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="uc-btn-accept-banner"]')[0]
python_button.click()
time.sleep(random.uniform(1.0, 3.0))
python_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="classified_9312278"]')[0]
python_button.click()
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

area = list()

for i in range(15):
    python_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="classifiedNavigation"]/ul/li[2]/a')[0]
    python_button.click()
    time.sleep(random.uniform(1.0, 3.0))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
    try:
        for table in soup.findAll("th",text=re.compile("Living area")):
            if table:
                area.append(table.find_next("td").next_element.strip())
            else:
                area.append(None)
    except:
        area.append(None)

houses = {"Area":area}
print(houses)
```

However with the current code, only exisiting value appends to the list - whatever is not added does not even leave a blank.
And here is a link to the [search](https://www.immoweb.be/en/search/house/for-sale?countries=BE&page=1&orderBy=relevance)
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty much obvious to me now

```
if soup.findAll("th",text=re.compile("Living area")):
            for table in soup.findAll("th",text=re.compile("Living area")):
                    area.append(table.find_next("td").next_element.strip())
        else:
            area.append(None)
```